# How to count numbers less than a given number including duplicates

Tags: python

I have a task to count numbers less than a given number. I understand this for most cases except ones with duplicates. So for example a list [1,2,2,3,4] I want the out put of this to be a count of 2 since it not including the middle one

One way I’ve tried this target is the number is the given number to find the less than to

```
count=0
for i in list:
    if i< target:
        count=count+1
return count
```

I know if I put = it will count both twos how can I fix this with what I have now and it still being a list

Comment: You can convert the list to a set.

Comment: Please provide a minimum workable code. Yours has `return` without it being inside a function. 
Also don't use the built-in name `list` as variable name

Comment: Do you need to count elements in a list smaller than a target element? Is the list sorted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would first remove duplicates like this:

```
res = []
[res.append(x) for x in list if x not in res]
```

and then you could get the number of values in the list without duplicates with the `len` function: `len(res)` or check each value to make sure it meets criteria before counting like being less then a number:

```
count = 0
for i in res:
    if i < target: count += 1
return count
```

Although it might be faster to create a list of numbers that are both not duplicates and meet the criteria, and then just take the length of that list:

```
res = []
[res.append(x) for x in list if x not in res and x < target]
return len(res)
```

Comment: This is bad python code, you should not use a list comprehension for side effects. Also referring to `res` in the loop and using `in` repeatedly is highly inefficient, the complexity is quadratic. Any of the other 3 answers is a much better approach.

Answer (score 1):

Put all the list items into a `set` and then count the number of elements less than `target`:

```
>>> a_list = [1, 2, 2, 3, 4]
>>> target = 3
>>> sum(i < target for i in set(a_list))
2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just change list to a set. That is, loop through a set of the list. This way you will go through each unique element once. See the code below:

```
count = 0
for element in set(list):
    if element < target:
        count += 1
print(count)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use a list comprehension:

```py
target = 3 # can be any other number
len([x for x in set(myList) if x < target])
```